# How long does 5lb of C02 last you?

Tags: carbonation, kegging

I can never get a grip on how often I'll need to refill my C02. Sometimes it seems to last forever other times it seems very quick.

In general, if you are just using C02 to pour, how many soda kegs can you get through on the same tank?

How many kegs do you get if you are also force carbonating?

Answer (score 6):

*If all your seals are airtight* a 5 pound tank should last you many kegs. Too many for me to keep count.

Bad gaskets, improperly seated poppets and bad hose connectors or clamps cause small leaks that will drain your CO<sub>2</sub> in no time. Some keggers only connect the gas line to the keg when it starts to peter out.

Comment: Tight seals are the key.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your responses. I think its time I really inspect my gear.

Comment: Thanks again, I changed some o-rings and bought some keg lube and now I'm back in business!